# Element is undefined in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, undefined

I am testing an app in angular and JHipster.

I try to test a label like this:

```
<label  #hiddenLabel class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="oncosupApp.paciente.nombre"  for="field_nombre" >Nombre</label>
```

and it gives the error that the hidden is undefined, that means that it doesn't take the reference of the HTML element.

Then I try without jhiTranslate like this:

```
<label  #hiddenLabel class="form-control-label"   for="field_nombre" >Nombre</label>
```

and everything works perfectly.
The testBed code is here and I haven't included any translation functionality from jhi cause I am a newbie in JHI and don't know what to insert:

```html
imports.....

describe('Component Tests', () => {

    describe('Paciente Management Dialog Component', () => {
        let comp: PacienteDialogComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<PacienteDialogComponent>;

        beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [OncosupTestModule,
                    OncosupSharedModule,
                    BrowserModule,
                    FormsModule,  
                ],
                declarations: [PacienteDialogComponent,
                ],
                providers: [
             JhiAlertService, ],
                     schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
            })
            //.overrideTemplate(PacienteDialogComponent, '')
            .compileComponents();
        }));
        
         beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PacienteDialogComponent);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
            //service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(PacienteService);
            //mockEventManager = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(JhiEventManager);
            //mockActiveModal = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(NgbActiveModal);
        });
        
          fit ('first test asdsadfdfd', async(() => {
             expect(comp.hidden.nativeElement.innerHTML).toContain('Nombre');
            }));
```

My component :

```html
imports...



@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-paciente-dialog',
     template: require('./paciente-dialog.component.html'),
    styleUrls: [
        'paciente.css'
    ],
})
export class PacienteDialogComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild('hiddenLabel') hidden: ElementRef;
```

This means that jhiTranslate is not permitting me to take the reference of the HTML element. How can I fix this? I cannot remove jhiTranslate, cause the app is not mine. I just need to test it.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of the testing, is the translate functionality made available in the testbed?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the question

Comment: Please post the code of your component too, it seems you renamed your template variable in your component and we can't guess if it's true or not.

Comment: Yess, it is true. I have renamed it I edited te question.